# Is this code really asynchronous?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have the code below in a WCF service running in IIS Windows Server 2016.

Is this code really runs asynchronous ? I am asking you because DoStep takes about 350ms, but when I send 250 requests per minute (1 request per 120 ms , my service seems to  have a significant delay.

Is this delay (about 30sec in most of calls) normal ?  Each request opens 19 tasks.

The server isn't something special, just has 4 CPU and 64GB RAM

```
var aAsyncTasks = new Task[19];
AsyncResult = new AsyncDataClass[19];
//Start Process
for(aa=0;aa<18;aa++)
{
    AsyncResult[aa] = new  AsyncDataClass();
    //Start Async Proccess
    Func<Task> aAct = async () {
          await    DoStep( AsyncResult[aa]).ConfigureAwait(false);
    };
    var aCurrentTask = aAct();
    aAsyncTasks[aa] = aCurrentTask;
}
//wait for all tasks
Task.WaitAll(aAsyncTasks);
//Manage all AsyncResults
..............

private async Task DoStep(out AsyncDataClass aResultData)
{
    await Task.Run(  () => {
     // Do Job here. **It takes about 350 ms**
   });
}
```

Comment: Try await Task.WhenAll instead of WaitAll.

Comment: The whole code does not make sense at all. Too much use of async/await and wrong use of out arguments

Comment: Is it possible to help me ? Please can you write this code with  correct way ? I am new multitasking

Comment: Have a look at https://dotnetfiddle.net/72sMh2

Comment: The `out` is wrong, there is 18/19 confusion..  See if you can write a [mcve]. It also matters how you call this from WCF.

Comment: I do not think this is the code which is running on your server. Async methods cannot have out parameters.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2f48a52-e35a-4948-844d-828a1a6deb74/why-async-methods-cannot-have-ref-or-out-parameters